# Creating columns in C language

Tags: c, dev-c++

I have these lines in my program:

```
printf("%-29s\n",("%s, Capital", CO));
printf("%-29s\n",("%s, Drawing",CO));
```

and when I run the program, it only shows the `%s` equivalent (`CO`) instead of `"%s, Drawing"`

Please help?

Comment: What is your desired output?

Answer (score 1):

You used the comma operator and the behavior is normal.

An expression with comma operator `A, B` means that first evaluate `A`, ignore its result, then evaluate `B` and the result of comma operator will be its value.

If you want to show "%s, Drawing", print it.

```
printf("%-29s\n","%s, Drawing");
```

Answer (score 0):

As MikeCAT has already stated, you have used the comma operator. If you want to left-align the compound string, you can achieve it by first printing to a temporary buffer with `snprintf`:

```
    char tmp[30];

    snprintf(tmp, sizeof(tmp), "%s, Capital", CO);
    printf("|%-29s|", tmp);

    snprintf(tmp, sizeof(tmp), "%s, Drawing", CO);
    printf("|%-29s|", tmp);
```

Of course, given that you print a newline directly after the string (and the justification is therefore somewhat pointless), you might as well just print the desired format directly:

```
    printf("%s, Capital\n", CO);
    printf("%s, Drawing\n",CO);
```